# Metronome in Rust, Audio Handling and Threading

Tags: multithreading, rust, audio

for learning purposes (and I found it kinda useful), I built a very basic command-line based metronome in rust. It's the first actual smaller project I built in rust.

It consists of 4 source files.
What I'm most concerned about:

- Audio Handling: At the moment i'm loading the audio files on the fly, every time I want to play a sound, which is redundant, obviously. Is there a way to embed the audio files into the executable? Or alternatively at least preload the files at the start of the app. I already tried this, but I had problems with the reusage of the buffer.
- The metronome is supposed to be controllable from the main thread. Is that a sensible to implement that functionality? (Currently, only Stopping is implemented, as I first wanted to get the basic Threading functionality down)
- I'm mainly coming from Python and C++, so I'm afraid I'm applying patterns I'm used to from those languages.

The source code:

main.rs

```
mod audio_handling;
mod io;
mod metronome;

fn main() {
    audio_handling::check_audio_files();

    let metronome: metronome::Metronome = io::ask_metronome_settings();

    let worker = metronome.start();
    loop {}
}
```

io.rs

```
use crate::metronome::Metronome;
use std::io;

pub fn ask_metronome_settings() -> Metronome {
    let mut bpm = String::new();
    let mut time_signature = String::new();

    println!("Please enter the BPM for ♩ = (0-65536):");
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut bpm).expect("You failed!");

    println!("Please enter the time signature, (Format: \"x/y\"):");
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut time_signature)
        .expect("You failed!");

    let bpm: u16 = match bpm.trim().parse() {
        Ok(num) => num,
        Err(_) => 0,
    };

    let numbers: Vec<u8> = time_signature
        .trim()
        .split("/")
        .map(|x| x.parse().expect("Error parsing time signature"))
        .collect();

    Metronome::new(bpm, numbers[0], numbers[1])
}
```

metronome.rs

```
use std::sync::mpsc::{channel, Sender};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
use std::time::Instant;

use crate::audio_handling::AudioSettings;
use crate::audio_handling::TicToc;

pub fn calc_beat_delta(bpm: u16, lower: u8) -> Duration {
    let quarter_note_sec: f64 = 60f64 / bpm as f64;
    let factor: f64 = 4f64 / lower as f64;

    Duration::from_secs_f64(quarter_note_sec * factor)
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct TimeSignature {
    upper: u8,
    lower: u8,
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct MetronomeSettings {
    bpm: u16,
    time_signature: TimeSignature,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum MetronomeControls {
    Stop,
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Metronome {
    metronome_settings: MetronomeSettings,
    current_beat: u8,
    last_time_run: Instant,
    beat_delta: Duration,
}

impl Metronome {
    pub fn new(bpm: u16, upper: u8, lower: u8) -> Metronome {
        Metronome {
            metronome_settings: MetronomeSettings {
                bpm,
                time_signature: TimeSignature { upper, lower },
            },
            current_beat: 0,
            last_time_run: Instant::now(),
            beat_delta: calc_beat_delta(bpm, lower),
        }
    }
    fn next(&mut self) {
        self.current_beat = (self.current_beat + 1) % self.metronome_settings.time_signature.upper;
        self.last_time_run = std::time::Instant::now();
    }

    fn play_beat(self) {
        let audio_settings: AudioSettings = AudioSettings::load();
        match self.current_beat {
            0 => audio_settings.play(TicToc::Tic),
            _ => audio_settings.play(TicToc::Toc),
        }
    }

    pub fn start(mut self) -> Sender<MetronomeControls> {
        println!("Metronome started!");
        let (tx, rx) = channel();

        thread::spawn(move || loop {
            self.play_beat();
            let sleep_time = self.beat_delta - (Instant::now() - self.last_time_run);

            let msg = rx.recv_timeout(sleep_time);
            match msg {
                Ok(MetronomeControls::Stop) => break,
                Err(_) => (),
            }

            self.next();
        });

        tx
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_calc_beat_delta() {
        assert_eq!(calc_beat_delta(120, 4), Duration::from_millis(500));
        assert_eq!(calc_beat_delta(119, 4), Duration::from_secs_f64(0.50420168));
        assert_eq!(calc_beat_delta(119, 8), Duration::from_secs_f64(0.25210084));
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_metronome_next() {
        let mut metronome: Metronome = Metronome::new(120, 4, 4);
        assert_eq!(metronome.current_beat, 0);

        metronome.next();
        assert_eq!(metronome.current_beat, 1);
        metronome.next();
        metronome.next();
        assert_eq!(metronome.current_beat, 3);
        metronome.next();
        assert_eq!(metronome.current_beat, 0);
    }
}
```

audio_handling.rs

```
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::path::Path;

const TIC_PATH: &str = "./tic.wav";
const TOC_PATH: &str = "./toc.wav";
const AUDIO_FILE_PATHS: [&str; 2] = [TIC_PATH, TOC_PATH];

pub fn check_audio_files() {
    for file_path in AUDIO_FILE_PATHS.iter() {
        if !Path::new(&file_path).exists() {
            panic!("Audio files missing!");
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum TicToc {
    Tic,
    Toc,
}

pub struct AudioSettings {
    device: rodio::Device,
}

impl AudioSettings {
    pub fn load() -> AudioSettings {
        AudioSettings {
            device: rodio::default_output_device().unwrap(),
        }
    }
    pub fn play(self, what: TicToc) {
        let file_path = match what {
            TicToc::Tic => TIC_PATH,
            TicToc::Toc => TOC_PATH,
        };
        let audio_file = std::fs::File::open(file_path).unwrap();
        rodio::play_once(&self.device, BufReader::new(audio_file))
            .unwrap()
            .detach();
    }
}
```

If you want to compile it, the code can be found here:
https://github.com/zapfdk/rust-metronome